# Sort entries by related entry title

Tags: relations, ordering

I’m trying to sort entries from a section called *exhibitions* by `startDate` and then by the `title` field of a related *gallery* entry. So  *exhibition* entries with the same `entry.startDate` are ordered alphabetically by `entry.gallery|first.title` if you will.

I know I can use SQL statements in the `order` attribute for `craft.entries.section('exhibitions').order('...')`. Is it possible to achieve something similar to the answer given in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786849/sorting-with-related-tables-in-mysql with the `craft.entries` API from a twig template?

The other solution I discovered was using a [Preparse Field](https://github.com/aelvan/Preparse-Field-Craft) and have it save the `gallery|first.title` on the exhibition entry and then query entries like this: `craft.entries.section('exhibitions').order('startDate, galleryTitle')`. I would prefer not to use this trick however.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions on this topic.